# Using reduce... merge in R causes extensive duplication

Tags: r, csv, merge

I have 13 csv files each with 315-320 observations of a total of 26 variables plus an id column that I would like to merge in R.  I attempted this using the following code:

```
filenames<-list.files(path="mergefolder")
mergedata<-llply(filenames, read.csv)
allcases<-Reduce(function(x,y) {merge(x,y, all=T, by="studyid")},mergedata, accumulate=F)
```

However, the final product (allcases) is a file with extensive replication for a total of 3422736 obs.

Can someone point me to what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a hunch, it might be blowing up with NULLs. Note this in ?merge: `DBMSes do not match 'NULL' records, equivalent to
     'incomparables = NA' in R.`

Comment: If you have multiple instances of your by variables you get Cartesian cross-products of rows for every possible combination. Are you sure you want `merge` and not `rbind`?